# Nodejs how to debug errors when running on production mode?

Tags: node.js

This is the error:

```
/home/api/.pm2/logs/api-error.log last 15 lines:
0|api      |     at s (/home/api/main/dist/app.js:1:120558)
0|api      |     at /home/api/main/dist/app.js:1:120617
0|api      |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
0|api      |     at /home/api/main/dist/app.js:1:120499
0|api      |     at /home/api/main/dist/app.js:1:123542
0|api      |     at /home/api/main/dist/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:73:24
0|api      |     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:188:21)
0|api      |     at runInAsyncScope (/home/api/main/dist/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:195:16)
```

I don't have a stack trace in here, probably because it built using webpack build targeted to production.

How can I see what actually happen and also enjoy the production environment, which saves the build size low?
Should I add a sourcemap for this?
Any tips in here will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like using a package named node-file-logger, which is pretty simple to setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-file-logger

I generally have a log file which logs errors with the method name, path to method, the error as shown below

```
00:14:25.686 | Error | 'read ECONNRESET' | Service: services->global->forgotPassword | Method: requestOtp |
```

Here is my code for that

```
router.get('/getFieldAgents', verifyTokenUser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        your code
    } catch (e) {
        log.Error(e.message, 'services->adminWebUser->admin->users->fieldAgent', 'getFieldAgents');
        return res.status(500).send({ 'status': false, 'login': true, 'message': 'Error getting Field Agents List' });
    }
});
```

So when ever it goes to catch it creates a log with the present date and logs errors into it

[image: my logs folder]